# Change the excerpt of every post on a category page

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a category page every post has a different excerpt. I need to trim down that excerpt with javascript depending on window width. I removed the code with window width as it is not relevant. My issue is that the current code replaces all excerpts with the first one. Obviously because `theString` takes the first value.

You can see here the code:

```js
function trimWords(){
  var contentWidth = $(window).width(); //get width of browser
  var maxLength = 20 // maximum number of characters to extract
  
  //trim the string to the maximum length
  var trimmedString = theString.substr(0, maxLength);

  //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
  trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")));
  $(".trimmed-words").html(trimmedString);
}
if ($(".trimmed-words").length > 0){
  var theString = $(".trimmed-words").html(); //issue here. it takes only the first value from the first div
  trimWords();
  $(window).resize(trimWords)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    first first first first first first first
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    second second second second second second 
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    third third third third third third third 
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    fourth fourth fourth fourth fourth fourth 
    </div>
  </div>
```

I need to do something along these lines:

```
$(".individual-post").each(function(){ //loop through every div
    var theString = $(this).find(".trimmed-words").html();              
    trimWords(theString);
});
```

But I can't manage to transfer the value of `theString`.

I would appreciate any help that would point me into the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: you need to execute `trimWords` by getting as a parameter `theString` inside a loop which cycles through `.individual-post` elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your code is a bit "dangerous", because of variable defined in global scope and used inside functions etc...

Moreover you need to cycle through the `.trimmer-words` elements in order to get all the strings, instead you get only the first. So I would chage your code a bit, just cycle through the elements, read the original string, use the `trimWords` function to cut the string and then update the element html. Here comes the code.

I've kept it as much as similar as yours.

```js
function trimWords(theString){
  
  var contentWidth = $(window).width(); //get width of browser
  var maxLength = 20 // maximum number of characters to extract
  
  //trim the string to the maximum length
  var trimmedString = theString.substr(0, maxLength);
  console.log(trimmedString);

  //re-trim if we are in the middle of a word
  trimmedString = trimmedString.substr(0, Math.min(trimmedString.length, trimmedString.lastIndexOf(" ")));
  return trimmedString;
}

$(".trimmed-words").each(function(index, item) {
  var theString = $(item).html();
  var trimmedString = trimWords(theString);
  $(item).html(trimmedString);
});

$(window).resize(trimWords)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    first first first first first first first
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    second second second second second second 
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    third third third third third third third 
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="individual-post">
  <div class="trimmed-words">
    fourth fourth fourth fourth fourth fourth 
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! you saved me a lot of time